# Why this loader doesn't work in jQuery 3.3.1

Tags: jquery

I've been using this little piece for loaders and fade ins with jQuery 1.11.2. Now I switched to jQuery version 3.3.1 and it no more work. Why is that?

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $(".loader").fadeOut(250);
})
```

Comment: (See https://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/3.0/#breaking-change-load-unload-and-error-removed)

Answer (score 0):

Try `$(document).ready` instead:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".loader").fadeOut(250);
})
```

That performs the `$(".loader")` DOM query after the DOM has already been loaded.